# Trigonometry problem.

Tags: trigonometry

If $ \sin\theta = n\sin(\theta + 2\alpha)$, then $\tan(\theta + \alpha) $ is equal to? 
I tried evaluating $n$, however I got no conclusive answer. I tried expanding $\sin(\theta + 2\alpha)$, but to no avail. How do I proceed?

Comment: Hint: Let $x=\theta+a$ then $\theta=x-a$, $\theta+2a=x+a$, and $$\sin(x\pm a)=\sin x\cos a\pm\cos x\sin a.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To point you in the right direction if $sin\theta = n sin(\theta + 2\alpha)$ and we know that $tan\theta = sin\theta / cos\theta$ then how might we find the next relationship? Another option to consider is Euler's formula:

\begin{align}
\cos x & ={e^{ix} + e^{-ix} \over 2} \\
\sin x & ={e^{ix} - e^{-ix} \over 2i}
\end{align}

Comment: What is Euler's formula?Can you please elaborate?

Comment: See above edits